# How to get the complete "java -cp xxxx com.xxx.class" command issued internally by eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Now my project works inside eclipse, but when I try to run it ,lots of jars are missing.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative: Switch to **Navigator** view and open the projects file **.classpath**. All related projects, jars and user libs, that are used by eclipse to assemble the classpath, are listed in this xml file.

---

Better approach: add the following line to your code and capture the output:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

This is the classpath as seen from the applications perspective. You can use the result as a value for the `-cp` parameter (paths should be absolute).

Comment: I found this file,but it can't be used as is:`<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/commons-lang"/>`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few option. In the package or project explorer you can right click, select "build path" and then modify the build path. This will open a listing of all jars on your build and execution class path.

Another alternative is to export the project as an executable jar, assuming you are okay with it jarring your program and all of the dependencies into a single jar. I think this is probably the ideal solution for you as it will produce a single file which may be double clicked to launch your application. Or, in a non GUI environment, may be run by executing `java -jar MyJar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

The "File->Export->Java->Runnable JAR file" allow you to create a runnable jar with all the dependencies present.  After invoking this, you will be able to execute your program as

```
 java -jar my.jar
```

I would strongly suggest - for technical reasons - that you use the "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR" option.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the wrong question here. Eclipse almost certainly doesn't issue a command of that form at all. What you really want to know is what CLASSPATH Eclipse uses when executing your code. That's just a matter of what *you* have told Eclipse about in the way of library dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your code: System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

Oh.. someone beat me to it. Oh well ;)